# boto3 receive all results from paginator as a single dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pagination, boto3

In some cases we want to return all possible values that are returned from the given method in the paginator. I was asked to write a wrapper for paginator methods to receive all pages, and return as a single result (single dictionary with the all the values together).

For example when using `get_paginator('list_tasks')`, and then converting the result to a list - the received value is a list of dictionaries (list of pages).
I want to receive only a single dictionary from this operation.

I figured I'll just merge all those dictionaries, and that is what I'll probably do, but I'm not sure this is best practice and maybe I'm missing something, since I don't see anything like it on the internet.

Comment: But what is your question or doubt? If you got the assigment to get all pages and return it as only one, yes you already figured out how to do it. If this is a bet pratice based on if the caller will use all data or not is another point, but if you got this specific assignment, that is it.

Comment: Can you show us the code so that we can help? It sounds like your approach is good, but the details are important here. Since paginators are essentially yielding data to the caller, you should be able to extend any list using just the paginator inside your wrapper.